# CAML Query for getting all files underneath a folder with treepath

Tags: 2010, search, caml-query, folder

I tried the U2U Caml Query Builder but I think it doesn't use the Recursive-Attribute the right way. 
I'm trying to build a query for getting all files underneath a folder (there a several folders under this one) with getting the treepath to this document. 
It's all for Sharepoint 2010.

Can you help me or suggest another tool where I can use the Recirsive Atrribute the right way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I helped myself.

I built a console-application with spsitedataquery and got all I needed.

Thanks

Comment: Care to add the code you have come up with? To help others with the same problem.

Comment: @Steffen-schindler yep i would definately up-vote if you fill in example code on your answer :-)